# Magento: Link products together in checkout/cart

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, product, configurable-product

How can I link products together?

Here's an example scenario.

Customer wants to buy carpet, which they can then choose to add underlay to. A Carpet is a configurable product, and Underlay is a Simple product

I have created an observer which listens to `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`, when this event is triggered, I check if they've selected to add underlay, if so, I programmatically add the product to the cart.

This all works fine, but the issue I'm having is when they view the shopping cart, there are two products in there. If the customer then adds a `different` Carpet with the `same` underlay, then there will be 3 products as the quantity will just be increased for the underlay.

Is there a way to link the products together at the point that they're added to the cart. So Carpet 1 and Underlay 1, is one product and Carpet 2 and Underlay 1 is another?

Hopefully this all makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was there some reason not to use [Bundled Products](http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-bundle-product-type-part-1/)?

Comment: Yes, due to the amount of products. This would mean there would be a bundled product for each combination of carpet, size, color, type of underlay, etc. Meaning there could be tens of thousands of products.

Comment: Cool, just wanted to make sure you were aware of the feature since it seemed like you are trying to recreate the feature yourself. There’s no reason Magento can’t handle tens of thousands of SKUs but I’m sure you are trying to make management simpler. If you must DIY maybe try extending the built-in features.

Comment: Yeah it is just the managing of them which would be an absolute pain.

I've tried storing a new value when the underlay is added to the cart, to store the Carpet's product ID. But I can't seem to get it to save to the database.